# JQuery: adding color style to input value only (jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery, input

How can I add color style just to the **value** of this input element (red, for example) while preserving the color of the input text black? I'd like to inject it into the external script and not embed it inline with the input element, if possible! Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/6KbqK/

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" value="Search apples" class="noquery" />
```

**JQuery**

```
$('input.noquery').on('focus',function(){
    if (!$(this).data('defaultText'))
        $(this).data('defaultText',$(this).val());
    if ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText'))
        $(this).val('');
});
$('input.noquery').on('blur',function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='')
        $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.noquery').on('focus',function(){
        if (!$(this).data('defaultText')) {
            $(this).data('defaultText',$(this).val());
            $(this).addClass("watermark");
        }
        if ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText')) {
            $(this).removeClass("watermark");
            $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    $('input.noquery').on('blur',function(){
        if ($(this).val()=='')
        {
            $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
            $(this).addClass("watermark");
        }
        });
    });
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6KbqK/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the color property and use the placeholder attribute for the default value.

```
<style> input { color: red; } </style>
<input placeholder="Bill" name="name">
```

Here's a demo, including styling placeholder text: http://jsbin.com/uqusut/1/edit

You may also just want to simply style it when it has focus.

```
input { color: blue; }
input:focus { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what want?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.noquery').on('focus',function(){
        if
            (!$(this).data('defaultText'))
            $(this).data('defaultText',$(this).val());
            $(this).addClass('red');
        if
            ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText'))
            $(this).val('');
        });
    $('input.noquery').on('blur',function(){
            if (($(this).val()=='')) {
                $(this).val($(this).data('defaultText'));
                $(this).removeClass('red');
                $(this).addClass('black');
            }
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.red { color: red; }
.default { color: black; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6KbqK/3/

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/6KbqK/5/

You should also cache your element it will improve performance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.noquery').on('focus',function(){
        if
            (!$(this).data('defaultText'))
            $(this).data('defaultText',$(this).val());
        if
            ($(this).val()==$(this).data('defaultText'))
            $(this).css('color', 'black').val('');
        });
    $('input.noquery').on('blur',function(){
        if
            ($(this).val()=='')
            $(this).css('color', 'red').val($(this).data('defaultText'));
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
input{
    color:red;
}
```

All I done was set the default css color to red. then when you change the value to  `''` change the    color to black then when you change it back to the default value change it back to red

**If you need it the other way around**

> ## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6KbqK/8/)